# How to add multiple column in a table on a button action

Tags: html, spring

I have a table were I want to add multiple columns with values when I click an add button. I have a drop down of Rulelist after selecting rule I have a button that rule pass to the controller search the object of that particular rule and display in a table. Now I am facing a problem after adding one column when I want to add another the first column gets removed.

Html

```
<form:form action="/update" method="post" id="ruleListForm" modelAttribute="ruleListContainer">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <h3 align="center">Selected Rule</h3>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id" width="25"> ID </th>
                <th data-field="details" width="20">RuleName</th>
                <th data-field="details" width="10">StartDate</th>
                <th data-field="details" width="10">EndDate</th>
                <th data-field="parameter" width="240">Parameter&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="ruleListContainer">
            <c:forEach items="${ruleList}" var="as" varStatus="vs">

                <tr class="rule">
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].id" value="${as.rule.id}" /> ${as.rule.id}</td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].ruleName" value="${as.rule.ruleName}" /> ${as.rule.ruleName}</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<input id="one" class="datepicker" type="text" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].startDate" size="11" height="0.10"></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<input id="two" class="datepicker" type="text" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].endDate" size="11" height="0.10"></td>
                    <td>
                        <table border="1">
                            <c:forEach items="${as.ruleParameter}" var="asss">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].ruleParameter[${assignments.index}].parameterName"value="${asss.parameterName}"> ${asss.parameterName}</td>
                                    <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].ruleParameter[${assignments.index}].parameterValue" value="${asss.parameterValue}" /> ${asss.parameterValue}</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="Name" value=""size="2"height="0.01">
                                            <select style="width: 80px;">
                                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                                    <c:forEach items="${targetlist}" var="target">
                                                            <option value="${target.displayName}"/>
                                                            <c:out value="${target.displayName}" />
                                                    </c:forEach>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
     <input type="submit" value="create">
</form:form>
<div>
        <form action="/submitrule" method="post" model="command">
             <table>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="6" align="right">
                    <select name="Id">
                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${listRules}" var="rule">
                            <option>
                                <c:out value="${rule.id}" />
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>

                 <input type="submit" value ="add"></td>
        </tr></table></form>
</div>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitrule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addruleSerch(@ModelAttribute ("SpringWeb") Rule obj2, ModelMap  model) {
    model.addAttribute("Id", obj2.getId());
     Rule rul = ruleApi.getRule(obj2.getId()); 
     ArrayList<Rule> rl1 = new ArrayList<Rule>();
      List<RuleParameter> ptr2 = rul.getRuleParameter();
      Iterator it = ptr2.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()) {
          RuleParameter r = (RuleParameter) it.next();
          System.out.println(r.getParameterName());
          System.out.println(r.getParameterValue()); 
     }
      rl1.add(rul);
      model.addAttribute("ruleList", rl1);
      return "hello";
}
```

How to add multiple column?

Thank you in advance for help/suggestions.